# How to see that kinetic energy depends on generalised coor., gen. vel. and time?

Tags: energy, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, differentiation

Let $u_{ik}$ denote the $i^{th}$ component of the position vector of the $k^{th}$ particle. Then kinetic energy of the system of $N$ particles is given by:
$$T=\frac{1}{2}\sum^N_{k=1}\sum^3_{i=1}m_k\dot u_{ik}\dot u_{ik}$$
Next, since $u_{ik}=U_{ik}(q_1, ... , q_n, t)$, we may write,
$$\dot u_{ik}=\frac{\partial U_{ik}}{\partial t}+\sum^n_{s=1}\frac{\partial U_{ik}}{\partial q_s}\dot q_s$$
My textbook says that therefore $T$ takes the form $$T=T(q, \dot q, t)$$
Now, I can see the explicit dependence on $\dot q$, but where is the explicit dependence on $q$ and $t$? Does it come from the fact that we evaluate the partial derivatives at particular coordinate or time?

### Note

Since there are a few similar questions, let me clarify what I am asking. My question is to do with how does one expression (that of $\dot u_{ik}$) imply that the kinetic energy is a function of $q$, $\dot q$ and $t$. So, my question is not asking can it depend on one or more of these quantities. It is asking given an expression, how does one conclude the dependence on the quantities I mentioned. In the other similar questions to this, the answers do mention that kinetic energy does depend on these three quantities but none of them tell how can one show mathematically that it does depend on them.

Comment: Why do you expect an *explicit* dependence? Why is the dependence on $q,t$ through the $U_{ik}$ not enough for you?

Comment: @ACuriousMind The third comment in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/314313/question-about-generalized-coordinates-and-kinetic-energy?rq=1) confused me.

Comment: @ACuriousMind So is it that we don't require explicit dependence? But then this way things should always be a function of time but sometimes $T=T(q, \dot q)$ only (there is one specific instance of this in the textbook I am reading). I think I am getting into a different question but could you please help clear this doubt?